# How to get the Smallest value from the Top 3 rows of the table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table name stocks with following colums;

```
Stockcode  Hig   low   Close   Date
MSFT     | 100 |  90 |  95   |2013-09-18
MSFT     | 105 |  96 |  97   |2013-09-17
MSFT     | 104 |  92 |  91   |2013-09-16
MSFT     | 101 |  88 |  100  |2013-09-13
```

I want to list the lowest value from the Low colum for last 3 days from the Date colum.

I tried the following query but it just giving me the lowest value from all days rather than last 3 days.

```
SELECT `LOW` 
  FROM `stocksdata` 
  WHERE `STOCKSYMBOL` = "MSFT" 
  ORDER by TIMESTAMP 
  DESC LIMIT 1;
```

How could I `SELECT` the values from the last 3 days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your data you're looking for the lowest value over the last three trading days:

```
select min(low) from(
    SELECT
        `LOW` 
    FROM `stocksdata` 
    WHERE
        `STOCKSYMBOL` = "MSFT" 
    ORDER by 
        TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 3) ltd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LOW 
FROM stocksdata 
WHERE STOCKSYMBOL = 'MSFT' 
AND date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -3 DAY) AND NOW() 
ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select min(low) 
from stocks 
where stockcode = 'MSFT' 
and date BETWEEN CURDATE() -INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm a bit confused on what your column names are, but you will need the mysql MIN() function in conjunction with a WHERE clause that limits your data to the date range you seek.  can you try this and let me know?

```
select min(`LOW`) from `stocksdata` where `Stockcode` = "MSFT" and `Date` > DATE_SUB(now(), interval 3 day);
```